# Elixir function guard clause for checking ranges compiles but does not work

Tags: elixir

Working on some exercise I came up with a (probably) not idiomatic solution which compiles flawlessly but does not behave as expected?

```
def span(xs, min, max), do: _span(xs,min,max)
defp _span([], _, _), do: []

# The following guard does not match
defp _span([head | tail],min,max) when min <= head <= max, do: [head | _span(tail,min,max)]

defp _span([head | tail],min,max), do: _span(tail,min,max)
```

The question is why does it compile but does not work?

Btw. I know the 'more' elixir-like solution might be this one (at least it does the job):

```
defp _span([head | tail],min,max) when head in min..max, do: [head | _span(tail,min,max)]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect this compiles since <= is left associative, so `a <= b <= c` is the same as `(a <= b) <= c`.

You can even verify this in the shell:

```
iex(1)> quote(do: 1 <= 2 <= 3)
{:<=, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [{:<=, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 2]}, 3]}
```

Consequently, `1 <= 2 <= 3` will amount to `true <= 3` and this will always be `false` since a number is always smaller than an atom.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this being in feature - in fact it is but not that way I thought of. Always should rethink your problem twice...

Answer (score 3):

It does compile since your guard clause `min <= head <= max` is valid Elixir syntax. As pointed out by sasajuric, `1 <= 2 <= 3` will amount to `true <= 3`. Notice that you can compare data of different types. In Elixir, the data types have a sorting order like below:

`number < atom < reference < functions < port < pid < tuple < maps < list < bitstring`